Pasar parámetros de un ciclo a otra consulta en Laravel manteniendo Dimensión
necesito obtener todos los username, para eso obtengo todos id de los client y luego pasar como parámetros todos los id para obtener todos los username de los usuarios para luego combinarlos a una consulta que muestra todas las calificaciones y mostrarlos en un ciclo foreach en la vista, actualmente estoy pasando la posición 0 y devuelve algo como lo siguiente {"username":"usernametest"} , y el objetivo es que muestre mas de un resultado ya que no es equivalente a las calificaciones, gracias de antemano
$memberclient = User::select('uc.user_id_client')
         ->join('users_califications as uc', 'uc.user_id', '=', 'users.id')        
         ->where('users.id', $id)        
        ->get();



$memberusername = User::select('users.username')       
         ->where('users.id', $memberclient[0]['user_id_client'])      
        ->get();



$caliname = $califications->merge($memberusername);



 @foreach($caliname as $calification)               
    
                        <h1>{{ $calification }}</h1>                    
                        
    
        
                    @endforeach


Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Te sugiero leer Cómo preguntar para mejorar tu pregunta y que sea mejor recibida. También, aprovechar y hacer el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos. No se entiende bien la descripcion del problema,  la gramática y la puntuación son importantes para poder leer. Puedes modificar la pregunta presionando en editar

Mejore la relacion muchos a muchos de las tablas, por lo tanto con 1 sola consulta omito pasos extras $memberclient = User::select('uc.user_id_client','uc.username_client')
->join('users_califications as uc', 'uc.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->where('users.id', $id)
->get();
